# How do I disable language fallback on a template for a given language in multilingual site?

Tags: language-fallback

We are building a multilingual site and language fallback is enabled for all the languages to fall back to English language content. Though one exception is that, we don't want pages of a specific template on one of the language sites to fallback to English Language. 
My requirements are very similar to this post
[Disable Language Fallback for specific item language](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/disable-language-fallback-for-specific-item-language)
As per the answer in that post, using "Enforce Version Presence - Hide this item if no language version exists [shared]" settings, it disables the language fallback for all the language site. So it doesn't meet our requirement.
So How can I achieve disabling fallback on a specific template for a given language?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is patch the *GetLanguageFallbackItem* processor in the *GetLanguageFallbackItem* pipeline and check for your custom requirements:

```
public class CustomGetLanguageFallbackItem : Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetLanguageFallbackItem
{
    public override void Process(GetItemArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.Database.GetItem(args.ItemId);
        if (item != null && Sitecore.Context.Site != null)
        {
            // Check for custom requirements
            if (Sitecore.Context.Site.Name == "site-with-disabled-fallback" 
                && item.TemplateID == new ID("MY-TEMPLATE-GUID"))
            {
                return; // abort processor to disable fallback
            }
        }

        // Proceed with fallback processor
        base.Process(args);
    }
}
```

Config patch:

```
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <group name="itemProvider" groupName="itemProvider">
        <pipelines>
          <getItem >
            <processor type="My.Namespace.CustomGetLanguageFallbackItem, My.Namespace" 
                       patch:replace="Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetLanguageFallbackItem, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
          </getItem>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Note**: this has not been tested thoroughly. Please leave comment if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the feedback and potential solution. I will try it out and inform if it works. (though i may not be able get back this week).

Comment: Using line below will cause infinite loop

`var item = args.Database.GetItem(args.ItemId);`

You might need to use code below instead:

`var item = args.Result ?? ((object)args.ItemId != null ? args.FallbackProvider.GetItem(args.ItemId, args.Language, args.Version, args.Database, args.SecurityCheck) : args.FallbackProvider.GetItem(args.ItemPath, args.Language, args.Version, args.Database, args.SecurityCheck));`